# Sum values from multiple rows using vlookup or index/match functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the values in columns B, C, and D using a formula. I tried combining `SUMIF`, `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX` with `MATCH` but no luck.

I would like to look for France and then add the values in B, C and D.

I have tried:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A9,A1:D5,{2,3,4,},FALSE))
```

But it returns the total value from the first row and does not include the 3rd row:

```
     A              B                  C                   D
1  FRANCE          152                252                  354
2  ITALY           255                184                  328 
3  FRANCE          221                215                  114
4  SPAIN           215                255                  356
5  USA             125                222                  584
6  
7
8  TOTAL PER COUNTRY
9    FRANCE
10   SPAIN
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. what should be the output for your example?

Comment: i would like to lookup for france and then add the values in columns B,C,D,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="FRANCE")*B1:D5)
```

Comment: So I guess that returns 0 for every row where it isn't a match, and 1 for every row where it is?  That's clever as hell.

Comment: Logged in from my work computer just to let you know that this really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: what is difference with : =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5="FRANCE"),B1:D5)

Comment: @DT Have you tested that alternative?

Comment: This is genius. It is very simple and very very powerful.

Answer (score -3):

You should use Ctrl+shift+enter when using the =SUM(VLOOKUP(A9,A1:D5,{2,3,4,},FALSE))
that results in {=SUM(VLOOKUP(A9,A1:D5,{2,3,4,},FALSE))} en also works.

Comment: A simple copy paste from https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/05/excel-vlookup-sum-sumif